# Count and Compare rows Query Mysql PHP

Tags: php, mysql, count

I am a beginner in PHP, I want your help, if all rows of the query are correct: prints a message, if some or all do not meet the condition, print another message.

I need help with Qry and PHP sintaxis, i think i need use te COUNT, but i dont now exactly how do it.

Thanks.

My Table Name:  oder_product

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+
| id | item_id | shipping | delivery |
======================================
| 1  |    1    |   YES    |    NO    |  
======================================

======================================
| 2  |    2    |   YES    |   YES    | 
======================================
| 3  |    2    |   YES    |   YES    | 
======================================
| 4  |    2    |   YES    |   YES    | 
======================================
| 5  |    2    |   YES    |   YES    | 
======================================

======================================
| 6  |    3    |   YES    |    NO    | 
======================================
| 7  |    3    |   YES    |   YES    | 
======================================

SELECT * FROM oder_product WHERE shipping=’YES’ AND delivery=’YES’ AND item_id=‘2’;
```

PHP

```
If $result=all rows match;
Echo’ All Products match’;

else
Echo’ some products don’t match’;
```

Comment: Curly quotes `‘ ’` *beautiful, yet deadly*. Use a code "editor" and not some kind of Word processor.

Comment: I use TextWrangler, sorry, I'm not very skilled writing here in the forum

Comment: all those `‘ ’` need to be regular quotes `'` if that's what your code really is.

Comment: All used 'in my code, here simply wrong, but it is clear to me, I just need help with the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sql=SELECT * FROM oder_product WHERE shipping='YES' AND delivery='YES' AND item_id='2';
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
```

use mysqli_num_rows() to find number

```
$rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($rowcount>0){
echo 'All Products match';
}
else{
echo 'some products don’t match';
 }
```

Comment: this works well, but count results of the query, and does not know how not correspond, and always tells me that all correspond. I think I need a firts query counts all from ID=2 and then add the other query for compare? Thankyou

Comment: sorry i didnt get you? i am little poor in english

Comment: Thanks, solved the problem, first count the records of ID 2, then your example and end if $ result1 = result2 Echo '. And it works well. Thank you very much!

Comment: you need to check all the ids in a single query ?